# file_get_contents - How to handle a URL not being there?

Tags: php

If a URL is not accessible, then I need to handle it. From my tests, file_get_contents doesn't seem to return false when a page returns 404 or 502.

Am I missing a trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns false for me... php 5.3.5...

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/xyzabc")===false ? "Returned False" : "Did not return False"; ?>
```

Comment: :O "===" - That is most likely my problem. I was using ==

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `file_get_contents` to access a URL. It's much slower than curl, and it isn't hardly any easier. Not to mention, handling errors in curl is a lot more graceful:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($errmsg = curl_error($ch)) {
  echo $errmsg;
} else {
  // hooray
}
```

Comment: "Much slower"?  Not quite.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance  Yes, I agree with you, but don't mislead either.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @Brad I'm not. I hosted a test comparing curl, sockets, and the fopen wrappers for *years* proving this to people like you that argue it. Curl is faster than sockets by 1-2%, and it's faster than fopen wrappers by about 2-3x and handles errors much nicer.

Comment: @Brad And the linked answer shows that as well. What are you missing?

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear.  Yes I agree that Curl is faster, but "much faster" is a stretch.  Hands down, Curl is definitely my pick for any job.  I am simply pointing out that the speed difference isn't huge, depending on your use.

Comment: A few seconds isn't much in terms of what term you get to work. A few seconds is huge in terms of waiting on a single HTTP request to finish. When the fruit is hanging this low, it's almost sinful not to reach for it.

Comment: +1, didn't know that curl was quicker... because of it's configuration I somehow just assumed it was a clunky approach

Comment: @Jaitsu: The PHP curl wrappers are all functional and poorly thought out, but the underlying library, libcurl, is the de facto library for making HTTP requests on Linux. You can use it easily at the command line too (`curl [options] <url>`).

Comment: yeah, another good point... I use quite often in the terminal, but like you say PHP's offering isn't very well thought out, thanks for the heads up though

Comment: Thanks for this, I will modify my code to suit. Have marked Johnathan Hebert's post as the answer though as it answers my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the `$http_response_header` which changes after each request made via your `file_get_contents()` call

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_headers();` before and checking if in the response there is `200 OK`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use file_exists, which returns true or false, depending on whether the file exists.

```
<?php
$path='path/to/file.txt';
if (file_exists($path))
  {
  $contents=file_get_contents($path);
  }
// Process contents.
?>
```

Comment: @coreyward, according to the documentation, it does in fact work for URLs as of PHP5.  With limits depending on configuration...  See:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php